# Convert NSData from NSURLSession to JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, nsurlsession

I am aware that there are many similar SO questions that have a similar title to mine. I have checked them out and am still running into this problem.

I am trying to access an API that returns a string that should/could be formatted as JSON.

To retrieve this string as convert the string to JSON I'm using (unsuccessfully) this code:

```
NSError *error;

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:
                                  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                      NSLog(@"Response: %@",responseString);


                                      NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                                      id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];

                                      NSLog(@"%@",[json objectForKey:@"ID"]);


                                      NSLog(@"Json: %@",json);

                                  }];



    [task resume];
```

The NSLog(@"Response:...) returns a string that when I enter it into this website: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu confirms that the string is valid JSON.

Both NSLog's that are supposed to return a JSON value come back null.

What iv'e tried:

- NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                                           error:&error];
- NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                                           error:&error];

I have also now tried:

```
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:
                                  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


                                      NSMutableDictionary *jsonObject;

                                      NSError *err = nil;
                                      @try
                                      {
                                          jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
                                      }
                                      @catch (NSException *exception)
                                      {
                                          NSLog( @"Exception caught %@",exception);
                                      }

                                      NSDictionary *info = jsonObject;

                                      NSLog(@"Json: %@",info);

                                  }];



    [task resume];
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I get a NSDictionary (JSON) result.

Comment: What are you getting in responseString?

Comment: Is your JSON really a NSDictionary at top level? What about using the `error` parameter ?

Comment: It's pretty silly to convert `NSData` to `NSString` and right back to `NSData`. According to your code `data` and `jsonData` are identical

Comment: @vadian Aware of that but wanted to see what the output was for the string.

Comment: @MinkleGarg Im getting a String that is Valid JSON (checked on the website mentioned)

Comment: @huddie96 Okay, then try with my given answer

Comment: But anyway the extra step to convert it back is redundant. Are you sure that the root object of  the JSON is a dictionary? And handle the error.

Comment: @vadian ah... True lol! In that case it was just a dumb mistake. Thank you though.

Comment: @MinkleGarg I tried it, my comment is on your answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue:
If you read the error parameter of `+JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`, it will tell you this:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.}

As stated, your answer looks like this: `aStringKey = realAndValidJSONSurroundedByCurvyBrackets`, which is not a valid JSON.
After discussion in chat, you have contact with the server side, and it should be their responsibility to give proper JSON. Until they fix it, in order to keep working, you can do:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [@"aStringKey = " length] ) withString:@""];
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonFinal = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&jsonError];

if (jsonError)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", jsonError);
}
```

But remember, that's a "quick hack/fix" and shouldn't be left in final version and remove as soon as possible.

You tried:

```
NSError *err = nil;
@try
{
    jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog( @"Exception caught %@",exception);
}
```

The `@try{}@catch(NSException *exception)` shouldn't work since `+JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` shouldn't throw a `NSException` in your case, so in theory, there is nothing to catch, and but it may still not work (since there is a `NSError`). 
Of course, since `data` parameter should be non null, if it's `nil`, you'll get a `NSException` (which would log `Exception caught data parameter is nil`), but that's another issue and doesn't assure you that the parsing went wrong (because of invalid JSON like in our case) if there is no exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  NSMutableDictionary *jsonObject;

    NSError *err = nil;
    @try
    {
        jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog( @"Exception caught %@",exception);
    }

    NSDictionary *info = jsonObject;
```

Comment: @MinkleGrag Still null and no exception was thrown - See updated question for exactly how I placed it

Comment: NSData is also nil?

Comment: I don't believe so, It created the responseString that I mentioned before proved to be good JSON

Comment: show me the content you are getting in Responsestring. As this link provided by you is showing nothing http://jsonviewer.stack.hu

Comment: The link allows you to check text as see it as JSON. If it can't convert to JSON, the link will tell you but i will attack the string as well in the question

Comment: can you share the API?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126631/discussion-between-huddie96-and-minkle-garg).